# Which tense is used after the verb hope?

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

Which sentence is correct? Is there any rule for using any particular tense after the verb "hope"? We use these sentences in writing letters to each other.

1. I hope you **will be** hale and hearty.
2. I hope you **are** hale and hearty.

Comment: Why do you not think you can use either?

Comment: The verb tense will depend on whether you are expressing a hope about the present or about the future. **I hope that you are well.** - **I hope that you will soon be well.**

Comment: In English we often don't explicitly distinguish between "Present" and "Future" (for example, *I will leave tomorrow, I leave tomorrow,* and *I am leaving tomorrow* are normally equivalent). It's a slightly different context, but native speakers would often consider *That's my final offer. I hope **you're** satisfied* and *...I hope **you'll be** satisfied* to be completely equivalent and interchangeable. When in doubt, you should by default normally choose the ***simpler*** verb form.

Answer (score 1):

If you said you hoped that someone "*will be*" well, that would imply that they are not well at present.

When writing a letter, you may expect a delay between you writing it and the recipient reading it, but that doesn't matter - we tend to write letters as they are meant to be read. For example, a common, if slightly formal way to express this in a letter is to write "*I hope this letter finds you well*", which literally means your hope is that they are well when they read it.

Returning to your example wording - if you hope they are presently well, you should write - "I hope you *are* hale and hearty".